# pip install grab - error: MS Visual C++ 10.0 is required

Tags: c++, python, lxml, grab

Привет! Хочу поставить grab и lxml в том числе на свой python3.4.

Захожу в cmd пишу pip install grab. Выдает ошибку о том что якобы не установлен компиллер как я понимаю, хотя у меня стоят разные версии ms visual c++ 2010 2013 2012 2015. Скриншот ниже). В чем соль?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDPATE решения: монжо загрузить тут [Microsoft Express Visual C++ 10.0](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/D/9/1D9A6C0E-FC89-43EE-9658-B9F0E3A76983/vc_web.exe) после этого ошибка пропадает. Но дальше могут возникнуть другие ошибки. Поставьте Anaconda там большинство требуемых библиотек уже или установлены или устанавливаются одной строкой без мучений.

*Система Windows 8 64-bit
Python 3.4*

Нашел решение своей проблемы, как выше писал Мстислав Павлов, есть решение в "англиском" SO, но там такая неразбериха что убиваешь 2-3-4 часа а результата 0. В итоге оказался полезным совет - установки "бинарной" библиотеки уже скомпиленой - как я понимаю.

Так вот действия следующие (практически переведу совет от этого [оригинала](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26839880) убрав все лишнее ):

1. Скачайте уже скомпилированый lxml plugin (ну видимо библиотека).

> pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.3.5#downloads

- скомпилированные - для Windows, с расширением .exe в конце!

Если нужна другая версия можете выбрать её директорией выше

Если у вас система 64 битная, тогда вы можете взять "неофициальную" версию для x64

> www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

** это то что использовал автор "оригинального английского текста", у меня же стоял python32 на 64 битной винде, и я скачал по первой ссылке lxml-3.5.0.win32-py3.2*

Нажмите клавишу Windows + R , напишите cmd, нажмите Enter (запустится comandline).
У меня скачался архив в диск Z: (у вас может быть D: например), для это наберем:
z: нажмем энтер (поменяем диск), далее перейдем в директорию куда скачался .exe файл командой: cd z:\ваша_дириктория\загрузки\ нажмем enter. далее если все ок (можно проверить наличие файла командой dir), пишем easy_install lxml-3.5.0.win32-py3.2.exe энтер. Соответсвенно lxml-3.5.0.win32-py3.2 - незабудьте скопировать с той версии (файла) которую вы скачали.

зы: ссылки пока что оформить не могу - не хватает репутации - copy\paste please!

Comment: Отметьте свой ответ - "правильным"(галочка напротив вашего ответа)

Answer (score 0):

В английском сегменте SO уже есть несколько решений данной проблемы. Прочитать можно [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670365/python-pip-install-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-tried-all-solutions)

Если у вас трудности с английском, напишите в комментарии к моему ответу.

Comment: Спасибо! У меня с английским проблем нет, но у других возможно есть :) Ссылка которую вы дали ведет я бы сказал на "корзину" с кучей решений, попробовал самое популярное но так и не помогло ) Продолжаю поиск в этой же теме

Comment: Мстислав, хоть мне и удалось поставить lxml так как я писал выше, но возникают разного рода ошибки например etree и fromstring не импортируются из lxml (их там просто нет). Если вы решали проблему с ошибкой компилирования которая запрашивает Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 то посоветуйте что сделать. Так как из английского сегмента СО мне ничего не помогло.