# Библиотека lxml на Windows Python 3.4

Tags: c++, python, python-3.x, библиотеки, lxml

Windows 8 64-bit. Python 3.4 64-bit. lxml-3.5.0.win32-py3.2.exe установлено через easy_install.exe
Так же тестировалось на Python x32

Не получается вызвать fromstring , под Ubuntu  с этим скриптом все ок. В папке scripts попробовал поискать fromstring ничего нету. Как быть что делать?!

Вот вывод shell`a:

```
>>> import lxml
>>> from lxml.html import fromstring
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from lxml.html import fromstring
  File "Z:\Python34\lib\site-packages\lxml-3.4.4-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 не является приложением Win32.


from lxml.etree import XMLSyntaxError
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
```

p.s.: 3.6.0 версию через pip поставить не получаются выдает ошибку Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 2010 requiered . (пожалуйста не отсылайте на английский SO где 10 тысяч решений из которых ни одно мне не помогло  [pip install grab - error: MS Visual C++ 10.0 is required](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500582/pip-install-grab-error-ms-visual-c-10-0-is-required/500592#500592) уже создавал по этой проблеме тему)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Проблема решилась установкой Anaconda для Python 3.5 https://www.continuum.io/downloads
2. Для тех у кого проблема при установке и компиляции с Visual C++ 10.0 - вот [ссылка на рабочий компилятор Microsoft Express Visual C++ 10.0](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/D/9/1D9A6C0E-FC89-43EE-9658-B9F0E3A76983/vc_web.exe) - который решает эту проблему. Но дальше могут возникнуть другие неприятности.

Answer (score 1):

А почему библиотека lxml win32. Попробуй поставить для x64 отсюда http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml
Предварительно удали текущую версию pip uninstall lxml

Comment: Спасибо! Возможно подойдет - возможно пробовал - не помню. У меня было много версий python как 32 так и 64 - убивал по 2-3 дня на это дело. В итоге оказалось все легко для Windows лучше всего установить Anaconda (по крайней мере для таких новичков как я на мой взгляд)